# Problem when writing to a python and panda file

Tags: python, text-files, txt

Is the code in the image correct?
It does not open anything when executing it.
The code should copy the content of the first txt file and paste it into the second txt file separating it with "/ t" or am I wrong?

```
infile = mainpath + "/" + "customer-churn-model/Customer Churn Model.txt"
outfile = mainpath + "/" + "customer-churn-model/Tab Customer Churn Model.txt"
  

  with open(infile,"r") as infile1:
    with open(outfile,"w") as outfile1:
        for line in infile1:
            fields = line.strip().split(",")
            outfile1.write("/t".join(fields))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(infile)
df.to_csv(outfile, sep="/t")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't read the input file properly. Editing your loop would do the trick.

```
for line in infile1.readlines():
```